# Loop through sheets and delete those which do not meet a condition

Tags: vba, excel, finance

I am using an Excel model to pull stock data off Yahoo Finance.  The results for each stock are downloaded into a different worksheet within the Excel workbook. After running the model, the workbook has many sheets, some of which contain unusable data.

I am looking to create VBA code that loops through each worksheet and checks for a condition, namely if cell A66 contains the date `12/31/2014`.  If this condition is not met, the sheet needs to be deleted.

Comment: Excel has a nice feature that records macros. I would try using it to build the base of what you want to do, then go in and pick at your code.

Comment: Just don't forget to remove all the `Selection` and `.Select` and `.Activate` crap; work off actual sheet and cell references instead, and you'll have a much less brittle solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Macro.

```
Sub checkSheets()
    For i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(66, 1) <> CDate("12/31/2014") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! I'm sure OP will appreciate your code, however unlike the numerous discussion forums out there on this site we consider "gimmeh teh codez" questions off-topic - I've voted to close it as "too broad". Although it can be somewhat fun, answering such questions isn't *teaching* anyone anything.